# Risks of adding a remote git repository to current git svn repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-svn

I'm working in a rails project which uses *SVN* as central repository, but i'm working (locally) with *git-svn*, and I want to add a remote where i will only push *master* for testing purposes (i will push to Heroku).

I've read this from [chapter 9.1 of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client#Git-and-Subversion) (my emphasis):

> Don’t rewrite your history and try to push again, **and don’t push to a
>   parallel Git repository to collaborate with fellow Git developers at
>   the same time**. Subversion can have only a single linear history, and
>   confusing it is very easy. If you’re working with a team, and some are
>   using SVN and others are using Git, make sure everyone is using the
>   SVN server to collaborate — doing so will make your life easier.

I won't be collaborating with other Git developers (everyone else is using *SVN*), but before setting it up, i just want to be sure if there are any associated risks in doing this, and if so, what should/could i do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only for pushing to a repo so that you can then checkout/build/deploy, it won't hurt. That warning you noted is stated there so that you don't start moving around doing crazy things on the repo where you work with git-svn to relate to other developers also using git-svn (plus other restrictions) because of the way that revisions are kept on git-svn.